# How to resolve Maven compile error in 'Common' module dependency for Asteroids project

Tags: java, maven

I am having issues with a study project, that is a asteroids game. The game is in Java and uses Maven. The game consists of modules that Maven compiles, or should. That is my issue.

When trying to clean install my project, a compile error occurs in my "Common" module, which all other modules depend on which is very critical. I don't have any idea why it wont compile, as I've reached out to other students that has no problems compiling, even though we all have very similar code!

Below is what the terminal writes when I try to compile

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project Common: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :Common

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is the modules pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>dk.sdu.mmmi.cbse</groupId>
        <artifactId>AsteroidsEntityFramework</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>Common</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Common</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have tried to check if my SDK was the issue and tried changing it to a lower version, but no luck. Looking at the link in the error message it says its a MojoFailureException, so a plugin might be the problem.
I have not yet found any answer to my problem even by using some of the same code as some of the other students.

Comment: There should be an earlier part of the gradle log that actually mentions the compile error. Gradle is notoriuos about hiding compilation problems in tons of somewhat related other output, so it might be tricky to find. Search the log for "error" and you'll find it.